# Mojolicious and delayed WebSocket

Tags: html, perl, websocket, mojolicious

I have this code snippet, I'm trying to push a string to the server every X seconds like:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use Mojolicious::Lite;
use EV;
use AnyEvent;
use POSIX qw(strftime);

get '/' => sub {
    my $self = shift;

    $self->render('main');
};

websocket '/echo' => sub {
        my $self = shift;
        my $w;
        $w = AE::timer 3, 1, sub {
                    $self->send('Got it');
        };
      #  $self->send(strftime("Server $$: %a %b %e %H:%M:%S %Y", localtime));
};
app->start();

__DATA__
@@ main.html.ep
<html>
<head>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<table id="tableID">
<tbody>
</tbody>
</table>
<script type="text/javascript">
var ws = new WebSocket('ws://192.168.1.104:3000/echo');
      ws.onopen = function () {
        alert('Connection opened');
      };
      ws.onerror = function() { alert("Error"); };
      ws.onmessage = function (msg) {
          $("#tableID").find('tbody')
                       .append($('<tr>')
                       .append($('<td>')
                       .text(msg.data)
            )
        );

      };
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

AFAIK Mojo used `IO::Loop` event loop, which I guess should be fine with `AnyEvent`

This doesn't work and I'm wondering why.
When I remove the AE part and uncomment the simple `send`, I see the results in the browser.

P.S: Just experimenting with WebSockets and Mojo for some Project I will need to use Both Mojo and AnyEvent + WebSockets

Comment: can you please include the templates too?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem seems to be that the send message is trying to happen before the GET connection is upgraded to a websocket. I'm still trying to track it down, in the meantime this works.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use Mojolicious::Lite;
use EV;
use AnyEvent;
#use POSIX qw(strftime);

get '/' => sub {
    my $self = shift;

    $self->render('main');
};

websocket '/echo' => sub {
        my $self = shift;
        my $w;

        $self->on(finish => sub { Mojo::IOLoop->remove($w) });
      #  $self->send(strftime("Server $$: %a %b %e %H:%M:%S %Y", localtime));

        $w = Mojo::IOLoop->recurring( 1 => sub{
                    $self->send('Got it');
        });
};
app->start();

__DATA__
@@ main.html.ep
<html>
<head>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<table id="tableID">
<tbody>
</tbody>
</table>
<script type="text/javascript">
var ws = new WebSocket("<%= url_for('echo')->to_abs %>");
      ws.onopen = function () {
        alert('Connection opened');
      };
      ws.onerror = function() { alert("Error"); };
      ws.onmessage = function (msg) {
          $("#tableID").find('tbody')
                       .append($('<tr>')
                       .append($('<td>')
                       .text(msg.data)
            )
        );

      };
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

notice that in my example the debug output shows `101 switching protocols` while your example attempts to autorender `echo.html.ep`.

Also I changed the template to generate the websocket url.

**UPDATE:**

It seems that in order to connect to a websocket, its necessary to subscribe to an event. In this example I subscribe to the finish event, which you want to do anyway in order to stop the timer.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use Mojolicious::Lite;
use EV;
use AnyEvent;
#use POSIX qw(strftime);

get '/' => sub {
    my $self = shift;

    $self->render('main');
};

websocket '/echo' => sub {
        my $self = shift;
        my $w;
        $w = AE::timer 3, 1, sub {
                    $self->send('Got it');
        };
        $self->on(finish => sub{ undef $w });
      #  $self->send(L<Mojolicious::Controller/strftime("Server $$: %a %b %e %H:%M:%S %Y", localtime));
};
app->start();
```

**UPDATE 2:**

In order to clarify the problem, SRI has [added the following documentation to Mojolicious](https://github.com/kraih/mojo/commit/4707b5052cf53a5301fdeb4ff81ba07e7a1961ee):

> The connection gets established when you respond to the WebSocket handshake with a 101 response status, which happens automatically if you subscribe to an event with
>   "on" or send a message with "send" right away.

which explains the situation. The original code neither subscribes to an event nor does a `send` immediately. In almost all cases you do at least one of the two, in this case though :-)

Comment: Thanks. but wondering, using url_for in the template is a nice Mojo helper, but what if I want to use a secured websocket scheme (wss, instead of ws which I assume is the default for Mojo????)

Comment: in that case, IIRC, you may do `url_for('echo')->scheme('wss')->to_abs`. `url_for` returns a [Mojo::URL](http://mojolicio.us/perldoc/Mojo/URL), so you may want to read its documentation.